# How to convert 0.08 V of AC to DC

Tags: rectifier, low-voltage

I am using an insulated wire as an antenna, which is picking up 0.08 V of AC. I want to convert that to DC. I know I need to use a rectifier, however my configuration doesn't seem to be working. I have a diode with a forward voltage of 26 mV and reverse voltage of 30 V. I am using a multimeter to read my voltage. I have the negative side of my multimeter grounded. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to get *power* from the antenna?

Comment: I guess from capacitively coupling of mains power network.

Comment: What frequency, and what do you intend to do with the DC voltage?

Comment: Eugene - Yes I would like to eventually at least be able to power an LED bulb.

Comment: Bruce - My frequency is around 90 MHz. It's picking up radio waves. I'm just conducting an experiment but my goal is to be able to power an LED bulb. It's been done before, I've seen it all over the internet. I just want to be able to replicate it at this point.

Comment: You will be restricted to mosfets and timing for the rectification, or an ideal diode with an opamp

Answer (score 2):

Given you have enough power, you need to step up with a transformer first. No silicon device will work with such low voltage. But ve advised, what you are doing is a real challenge.

Comment: While an impedance transformer may indeed be a possibility, that is hardly the only possibility.  Plenty of silicon devices can handle *signals* of this voltage, and AC signals are readily capacitively coupled onto a DC bias if desired to achieve a different operating point.

Comment: Sure, but doesn't he want to take power from that?

Comment: That has only been added to the question in the last few seconds.

Comment: I really have good instincts :)

Comment: I don't want to use a transformer because my goal is to generate power just from what the antenna is picking up. Chris - do you have any suggestions on what devices I should use to receive that DC signal?